# How to automatically remove fields in a struct

Tags: xml, matlab, struct

I have an struct created from an xml file with 100 fields, this is an example of 3 fields:

```
Parameters.Processing.EnableFilter.Text = true
Parameters.Processing.CutoffFreq.Text = 3000
Parameters.Classification.Threshold.Text = 0.95
```

I want to remove the field "`Text`" and have a struct similar than:

```
Parameters.Processing.EnableFilter = true
Parameters.Processing.CutoffFreq= 3000
Parameters.Classification.Threshold = 0.95
```

This is the most similar thing I could find but it is not doing exactly what I want.

```
newName = '';
oldName = 'Text';
[a.newName] = a.(oldName);
a = rmfield(a,oldName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need recursion here

```
function fix = fixStruct( st, toRemove )
if isfield( st, toRemove )
   fix = st.(toRemove);
else
   fn = fieldnames( st )
   for fi=1:numel(fn)
       fix.(fn{fi}) = fixStruct( st.(fn{fi}), toRemove );
   end
end
```